# Issue with Loopback MongoDB Connector

Tags: node.js, strongloop

i am using special character $ in my Mongodb password.

this is how my connector looks like

```
 {
"name": {
"host": "using ip here",
"port": 27017,
"url": "",
"database": "",
"password": "example123$",
"name": "name",
"user": "username",
"connector": "mongodb"
 }
}
```

Error
 Cannot initialize connector "mongodb": Password contains an illegal unescaped character

is there a way i can use special character in Loopback connector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try with `%24`. ie `example123%24`

`%24` is the encoded value of `$`

```js
const enc = encodeURIComponent('$')
console.log('Encoded Value :', enc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls looking at issue #3764 on loopback Github.

https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/3764